# Is there a way to revert to an older version of an app I downloaded from Microsoft Store?

Tags: microsoft-store

A software I got from Microsoft Store (Autodesk Sketchbook) has recently been auto updated to the newest version, which has an issue and causes frequent crashing.

Is there a way I can undo the version update and use the older version again, without rolling back my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy easy of undoing the version update from the Microsoft Store,
or to ensure that it doesn't auto-update again.

But the good news is that you don't need the Microsoft Store version anymore.

The Autodesk Sketchbook is now free to download from
[sketchbook.com](https://sketchbook.com/),
as a desktop app.

Comment: Yeah, just found out about the non-store version too. I was able to turn off automatic updates in settings, but the actual Microsoft Store itself is very limiting when it comes to options.